# C# Web api duplex web socket

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket

I need a structure for send data

i use asp.net mvc 5 and i want to  send data to mobile device and wait return response.
how can it ?

(Web api or Mvc)  <-----> Mobile Device

Comment: I believe SignalR is still the .NET goto for web socketry: http://signalr.net/

Comment: signalR send data but not get response. i need data from client. for example string response = sender.send(data);

Comment: On an asynchronous message approach you do not block for an answer, you send a request with a correlation ID, and the other side will send you a message as response with the same correlation ID.

Comment: thanks i write it. i send ticket id for message and return this id but can i find better solution

Comment: You can use web sockets.
Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32554599/5675763